# Sort an array with the combiation of numbers, number_letters, letters_numbers and letters only

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to sort and array, however, unable to get the array as intended.

I have an array like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 7
    [2] => 8
    [3] => 9
    [4] => 10
    [5] => 11
    [6] => 12
    [7] => 13
    [8] => 14
    [9] => 15
    [10] => 16
    [11] => 17
    [12] => 18
    [13] => 19
    [14] => 20
    [15] => 21
    [16] => 23
    [17] => 24
    [18] => 26
    [19] => 28
    [20] => 29
    [21] => 30
    [22] => 31
    [23] => 32
    [24] => 33
    [25] => 34
    [26] => 35
    [27] => 36
    [28] => 37
    [29] => 38
    [30] => 39
    [31] => 40
    [32] => 41
    [33] => 42
    [34] => 44
    [35] => 46
    [36] => 48
    [37] => 50
    [38] => 52
    [39] => 54
    [40] => A
    [41] => B
    [42] => 3
    [43] => 4
    [44] => 6
    [45] => A1
    [46] => B1
    [47] => 1A
    [48] => 22
    [49] => 25
    [50] => 27
    [51] => 1B
)
```

When I run asort($arr) it returns:

```
Array
(
    [47] => 1A
    [51] => 1B
    [42] => 3
    [43] => 4
    [0] => 5
    [44] => 6
    [1] => 7
    [2] => 8
    [3] => 9
    [4] => 10
    [5] => 11
    [6] => 12
    [7] => 13
    [8] => 14
    [9] => 15
    [10] => 16
    [11] => 17
    [12] => 18
    [13] => 19
    [14] => 20
    [15] => 21
    [48] => 22
    [16] => 23
    [17] => 24
    [49] => 25
    [18] => 26
    [50] => 27
    [19] => 28
    [20] => 29
    [21] => 30
    [22] => 31
    [23] => 32
    [24] => 33
    [25] => 34
    [26] => 35
    [27] => 36
    [28] => 37
    [29] => 38
    [30] => 39
    [31] => 40
    [32] => 41
    [33] => 42
    [34] => 44
    [35] => 46
    [36] => 48
    [37] => 50
    [38] => 52
    [39] => 54
    [40] => A
    [45] => A1
    [41] => B
    [46] => B1
)
```

It is sorting normally, however, I am willing to have it sort according to combination such as Numbers, NumbersLetters, LettersNumbers, Letters.

For instance, this array should looks like:

```
Array
(
    [42] => 3
    [43] => 4
    [0] => 5
    [44] => 6
    [1] => 7
    [2] => 8
    [3] => 9
    [4] => 10
    [5] => 11
    [6] => 12
    [7] => 13
    [8] => 14
    [9] => 15
    [10] => 16
    [11] => 17
    [12] => 18
    [13] => 19
    [14] => 20
    [15] => 21
    [48] => 22
    [16] => 23
    [17] => 24
    [49] => 25
    [18] => 26
    [50] => 27
    [19] => 28
    [20] => 29
    [21] => 30
    [22] => 31
    [23] => 32
    [24] => 33
    [25] => 34
    [26] => 35
    [27] => 36
    [28] => 37
    [29] => 38
    [30] => 39
    [31] => 40
    [32] => 41
    [33] => 42
    [34] => 44
    [35] => 46
    [36] => 48
    [37] => 50
    [38] => 52
    [39] => 54
    [47] => 1A
    [51] => 1B
    [45] => A1
    [46] => B1
    [40] => A
    [41] => B
)
```

Comment: Which PHP functions have you used? ... try `natsort()`?

Comment: @PaulT. I have used `asort()`. I have tested `natsort` as well, however, it returns the same output as asort in my case

Comment: That is about compare number vs string. Is all your number like 27,27 on your array is Int or String ? what is your definition when A1 is greater than 1A ? All depend on your business logic. You may use uasort to custom your sort

Comment: could you provide me somewhere your php array to take it and do some testing codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use user defined sort with `uasort`, check the [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/51ecc490bd75a762da1b45eb750f3d00da6831b0)

```
uasort($array,function($a,$b){
    if(is_numeric($a) && is_numeric($b)){
        return $a - $b;
    }elseif(is_numeric($a)){
        return -1;
    }elseif(is_numeric($b)){
        return 1;
    }else{
        $length = max(strlen($a),strlen($b));
        return strcmp(str_pad($a,$length,"z",STR_PAD_LEFT),str_pad($b,$length,"z",STR_PAD_LEFT));
    }
});
```

Comment: It looks like it is working, however, could you please explain me what are those `$a` and `$b` variable refers to.

Comment: @AayushDahal It's the parameter of [value_compare_func](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php#refsect1-function.usort-parameters) of [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)